# Q/A and votes/newest selection in new profile aren't sticky when not logged in

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

On the new site design, when looking at the newest posts when not loged in, the selections aren't sticky.

- Go to a site you aren't logged in to.
- Look at the profile (new profile sites) of a user.
- Select Questions (it should be defaulted to all)

  - Note only questions are listed.
- Select the other sort order (probably 'newest')

  - Note that selector is back to 'All' (Questions and Answers are both shown)
  - Questions and answers are listed.

The expected result for selecting 'questions' and then 'newest' would be to see the list of questions, sorted by newest first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same way that any other "sticky" sorting/filtering option on the profile page is only remembered for logged in users.

This will not change.